# Accessing ClientRequest body in ExchangeFilterFunction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

My question is somewhat similar to [Can I access the request/response body on an ExchangeFilterFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103462/can-i-access-the-request-response-body-on-an-exchangefilterfunction)

I am using declarative [Spring Rest Http Interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/rest-clients.html#rest-http-interface) to call our internal APIs.

For every outgoing request, I have to sign the request and add a signature in the header.
The obvious thing is to do this in an exchange filter which is similar to the following.

```
@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {

    // There is no way I can get request body like in spring mvc
    String requestBody = request.body().toString();
    var signatureValue = signRequest(requestBody);

    // Add the Signature header
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(“signature”, signatureValue);

    var modifiedRequest = ClientRequest.from(request)
    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers)).build();
    
    return next.exchange(modifiedRequest);

}
```

Since I am not using either `restTemplate` or `webClient` directly, I am looking for a way to add the header possibly from a central place.
Any idea, suggestion, workaround, or solution is really appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to achieve this by implementing `HttpServiceArgumentResolver` and overriding `resolve` method.

The following is how body is read and header is added.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MySignatureHeaderResolver implements HttpServiceArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean resolve(@Nullable Object argument, MethodParameter parameter,
            HttpRequestValues.Builder requestValues) {
        Object requestBody = argument;
        RequestBody annot = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(RequestBody.class);
        if (annot == null) {
            requestBody = ""; 
        }
        String signatureValue = signRequest(timestamp + requestBody);
        requestValues.addHeader("signature", signatureValue);
        
        return false; // always return false, otherwise a correct request won't created.
    }
}
```

And then register this as a custom argument resolver (which is not in actual) to the http proxy factory.

```
@Bean
    public HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory(
            HttpServiceProxyFactory.Builder httpServiceProxyFactoryBuilder) {
        httpServiceProxyFactoryBuilder.customArgumentResolver(mySignatureHeaderResolver);
        return httpServiceProxyFactoryBuilder.build();
    }
```