# how to print complete http request in reactive spring

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I have implemented custom web filter and trying to read complete HTTP request but getting an error on subscribing

```
public class AppWebFilter implements WebFilter {

@Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        exchange.getRequest().getBody().map(m->m.read()).doOnNext(k->k.byteValue()).subscribe();
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Dvorog illegalstateexception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log request and response bodies in Spring WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240005/how-to-log-request-and-response-bodies-in-spring-webflux)

Comment: @pixel its not duplicate

Comment: Can you please explain how it's different?