# How to log Request/Response body using WebClient filters - Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I am using ExchangeFilterFunction to log requests and responses but I don't know how I can get the request/response body as a string or JSON format and log it.

The code looks as follows:

```
//logging method, url and headers, but the body of the request is needed

fun logClientRequest(): ExchangeFilterFunction {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor() {

        logger.info("Client CRM Request: {} {}", it.method(), it.url());

        //TODO: LOG HERE BODY REQUEST

        it.headers().forEach { name, values ->
            run {
                logger.info("Headers:")
                values.forEach { value -> logger.info("{}={}", name, value) }
            }
        }
        Mono.just(it)
    }
}

fun logClientResponse(): ExchangeFilterFunction {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor() {
        logger.info("Client CRM Response {}", it.bodyToFlux(Any::class.java))
        Mono.just(it)
    }
}
```

The bodyToFlux in logClientResponse() logs only:

```
ExchangeFilterFunction Client CRM Response checkpoint("Body from PUT https:myurl [DefaultClientResponse]")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log request and response bodies in Spring WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240005/how-to-log-request-and-response-bodies-in-spring-webflux)

Comment: Or this: [how to log Spring 5 WebClient call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46154994/4110190)