# Read request body in HandlerFilterFunction and pass to next handler if valid

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Use case is to validate data in JWT with request body.
JWT `sub` contains

```json
{
  "sub": "{\"data\": {\"street\": \"Street 1\", \"landmark\": \"TallestTower\"}}"
}
```

Request must contain exact data. Forbidden if not match, otherwise pass on for further processing.

Using:

- Springboot 3,
- WebFlux reactive with router functions
- Jose4j for JWT.

During debug, when it reaches to `ResourceRoutesHandler.create()` function, and tries to execute `request.bodyToMono().flatMap()`, it just exits with HTTP 200. There are several further processes in `.flatMap()` but they are not executed. Interestingly, there is no `ServerResponse.ok()` in the workspace to produce such result with HTTP 200.

My understanding this `ServerRequest.from(request).build()` is causing it.

Is there a way to validate request body and send the same request or within the same subscription?
Or is there an alternate way to validate request data before reaches to route handler?

#### Routes

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ResourceRoutes {

  final JwtHandlerFilterFunction jwtHandlerFilterFunction;

  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> createResource(ResourceRoutesHandler recourceRoutesHandler) {
    return RouterFunction.route(
            POST("/create").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
            recourceRoutesHandler::create
        )
        .filter(jwtHandlerFilterFunction);
  }
}
```

#### HandlerFilterFunction

```java
@Component()
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtHandlerFilterFunction
    implements HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {

  final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Override
  public Mono<ServerResponse> filter(final ServerRequest request,
                                     final HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> next) {

    Headers headers = request.headers();
  
    Optional<String> jwtToken = Optional.ofNullable(headers.firstHeader("Auth-Token"));

    return jwtToken.map(_jwt -> jwtValidateService
                       .validateReactive(_jwt)
                       .flatMap(verifyPayload(request))
                       .flatMap(validMessage -> next.handle(
                        // clone here and pass on to next
                        // this is causing fail to execute request in route handler
                           ServerRequest.from(request)
                                        .build()
                       ))
                       .onErrorResume(throwable -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                           .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                           .bodyValue("Authorization failed")
                       ) // jwt validation failed
                   )
                   .orElse(next.handle(request)); // to next if header not present
  }

  private Function<String, Mono<String>> verifyPayload(final ServerRequest clientRequest) {
    return subject -> clientRequest
        .bodyToMono(String.class) // as the body already read how to pass on to next handler?
        .flatMap(requestData -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
          // for simplicity
          if (!subject.equals(requestData)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid subject data");
          }
          return "Valid";
        }));
  }

}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi, try to look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240005/how-to-log-request-and-response-bodies-in-spring-webflux. It should help you a little bit because in principle, it's the same - accessing the request body in the HandlerFilterFunction/WebFilter.

Comment: Thanks @rasto. I could give it a try using WebFilter. In my example it is using `RouterFunction` for inbound requests. The signature of [RouterFunction.filter()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RouterFunction.html#filter(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.HandlerFilterFunction)) function expects `HandlerFilterFunction`. My understanding `WebFilter` will only work for `WebClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to rely on the request's body in an `HandlerFilterFunction`. Note that the `ServerRequest.from(...)` method doesn't copy the body, for a similar reason: body publisher can generally only be subscribed and consumed once.

not debating the whole arrangement further, I think you might have a way out in your case: since you read the whole body as a `String` in `verifyPayload`, you could perhaps merge your two jwtToken `flatMap`s into a single one by modifying the `verifyPayload` method like so:

```
private Function<String, Mono<String>> verifyPayload(final ServerRequest clientRequest, 
        //added the HandlerFunction as a parameter
        final HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> next) {
    return subject -> clientRequest
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .flatMap(body -> {
          // for simplicity
          if (!subject.equals(body)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid subject data");
          }
          //we have already read the full body, so we can "forward" it
          return next.handle(ServerRequest.from(clientRequest).body(body).build());
        }));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Simon Basle for your time. I will give it a try for this approach. RouterFunction `filter()` accepts HandlerFilterFunction. Relying on request body data is due to the use case, unfortunately not much of a choice. Maybe there is a need of another (overloaded or an interface supporting both ways) function `.filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, RouterFunctionChain chain)`, or similar.

Comment: Hi @simon, thank you for the solution to this specific problem. I have tried this approach and it worked without any issues. Appreciate it!